# Is it possible to have a mintTo CPI and transfer CPI within same program? The tests are passing for either one, but not both at the same time

Tags: anchor, cpi

```
        accounts: {
            pool: pool.publicKey,
            longPayer: longKeypair.publicKey,
            shortPayer: shortKeypair.publicKey,
            mint: gdTokenMint,
            authority: gdTokenKeypair.publicKey,
            from: longusdc,
            from2: shortusdc,
            transferTo: poolusdc,
            mintTo: poolgd,
            tokenProgram: Spl.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [pool, longKeypair, shortKeypair, gdTokenKeypair],
    });
```

```
            from: ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.transferTo.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.longPayer.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program1 = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx1 = CpiContext::new(cpi_program1, cpi_accounts1);

        token::transfer(cpi_ctx1, long_col)?;

        let cpi_accounts2 = Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.from2.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.transferTo.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.shortPayer.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program2 = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx2 = CpiContext::new(cpi_program2, cpi_accounts2);

        token::transfer(cpi_ctx2, short_col)?;

        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.mintTo.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, long_col)?; 
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatePool<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = longPayer, space = Pool::LEN)]
    pub pool: Account<'info, Pool>,
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub longPayer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub shortPayer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from2: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub mintTo: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub transferTo: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

The error message is not giving me any good leads.

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the transaction with `preflightChecks: false` so that you can get the full error message in the program logs. There's no issue with calling two CPIs in one transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue before and solved with zero copy. the problem with two cpi calls is that you need to copy the account info twice. Solana call stack has a fixed size for all the nested cpis. you can read more here: [https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#:~:text=Each%20stack%20frame%20is%204KB%20in%20size](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#:%7E:text=Each%20stack%20frame%20is%204KB%20in%20size). There's also a new address look up table coming up, aim to solve this problem, you can follow up here: https://docs.solana.com/proposals/transactions-v2